# MongoDB positional operator issue

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, positional-operator

I am trying to run the following update command with a positional operator.

```
businesses.update({ '_acl.5370b9af4a6b2a941ad3bf5e': 'read', 
'rooms._id': ObjectId("5370c1ca19b56d0200b26e7f"), 
_id: ObjectId("5370b9af4a6b2a941ad3bf58") }, 
{ '$set': { 'rooms.$.lastServiced': new Date("Thu, 15 May 2014 16:17:28 GMT") } } )
```

The query has 2 arrays, `_acl.5370b9af4a6b2a941ad3bf5e` and `rooms`. I want to update the rooms array using positional operator but my update goes to the wrong element in the rooms array.

This problem goes away if I remove this `'_acl.5370b9af4a6b2a941ad3bf5e': 'read'` part from the query.

I think that mongodb uses the position from the `_acl` array even though in the $set part I am using `rooms` array. Is this a bug in mongodb?

Comment: This should satisfy this directly when implemented: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831